# Am I allowed to change user info in notification

Tags: objective-c, hook

I need to create interruptible hooks in objective c. interruptible hooks should have the ability to abort an operation if any of the hooks callbacks interrupt the operation. I thought of using `NSNotificationCenter` for that like:

```
NSMutableDictionary *userInfo = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
[userInfo setObject: [NSNumber numberWithBool: NO] forKey: @"interrupted"];
[notificationCenter postNotificationName: @"Operation A will happen"
                                  object: self userInfo:userInfo];
if(![[userInfo objectForKey: @"interrupted"] boolValue])
{
    [self doOperationA];
}
```

and on the hook side

```
-(void) operationAWillHappen: (NSNotification *) note
{
    if(someCondition)
        [(NSMutableDictionary *)note.userInfo setObject:
         [NSNumber numberWithBool: YES] forKey: @"interrupted"];
}
```

Am I allowed to change the user info like that? is there a better way to implement interruptible hooks in objective c?

Answer (score 0):

That's entirely unsafe and you'll probably crash your app if you do it.

I think what you're looking for is the "[delegate or delegation pattern](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaFundamentals/CommunicatingWithObjects/CommunicateWithObjects.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002974-CH7-SW18)."

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that it works but since the API is an immutable object, you're not supposed to. It could break if it happens to work today.

You could always pass self in the dictionary, and have listeners send it a message.

(I assume you want to take advantage of the fact that you can have an arbitrary number of listeners -- delegation is much simpler but you get only one delegate.)